# Bounding Schur symmetric polynomials on the unit circle

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, symmetric-functions, schur-functions

Recall the Schur polynomial in $n$ variables, indexed by the partition $\lambda$, with $\ell(\lambda) \leq n$, is given by 
\begin{equation}
s_\lambda(x_1,\ldots, x_n) = a_{\lambda + \delta}(x_1, \ldots, x_n) / a_\delta (x_1, \ldots, x_n),
\end{equation}
 where $\delta = (n-1,n-2,\ldots, 0)$ and $a_\lambda = \det (x_i^{\lambda_j})$ is the Vandermonde determinant of the $n \times n$ matrix whose $(i,j)$ element is $x_i^{\lambda_j}$. My notation here is consistent with Ian Macdonald's Hall polynomial book chapter 1.

Also let $e_j$ be the $j$th elementary symmetric polynomial in $n$ variables, $0 \le j \le n$. These are defined by 
\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=1}^n (1 + x_i t) = \sum_{j=0}^n e_j(x_1,\ldots, x_n) t^j.
\end{equation}
By the Jacobi-Trudi formula we know that 
\begin{equation}
s_\lambda = \det(e_{\lambda^t_i -i + j}),
\end{equation}
 where $\lambda^t$ is the transpose of the partition $\lambda$, that is, $\lambda^t_i = \mid\{j: \lambda_j \geq i\}\mid$. Thus $s_{1^j} = e_j$, for $j \le n$.

Now we specialize to $x_i \in \mathbb{T}:= \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \mid z \mid = 1\}$. Given that
\begin{equation}
e_1(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = 0,
\end{equation}
 that is, $\sum x_i = 0$, I am interested in bounding $s_\lambda$.

I have a conjecture for $\lambda = 1^{n/2}$, and $n = 4m$, $m \in \mathbb{N}$, namely, 
\begin{equation}
\mid e_{n/2}(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \mid \le \binom{n/2}{n/4}.
\end{equation}
This is attained when $x_i = (-1)^i$, that is, when half of them equal $1$ and the other half equal $-1$, since 
\begin{equation}
\prod_i (1  +x_i t) = (1-t)^{n/2} (1+t)^{n/2} = (1-t^2)^{n/2}.
\end{equation}

I don't know if this conjecture is true for all qualifying $x_i$'s. Full credit will be given to solve this special case. However, I am also interested in a general conjecture for arbitrary $\lambda$.

Comment: Would an asymptotic bound be useful for you?  I can see how to get a bound of $2^{n/2}$ which is along the right lines, and one can probably save the $\sqrt{n}$ too (to almost get your conjecture).

Comment: @Lucia: $2^{n/2}$ is more than good enough for me! In fact, in general I am looking for a bound of the form $\mid s_\lambda(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \mid \leq \sqrt{\mid s_\lambda(1,\ldots, 1)\mid }$.

Comment: In fact for my actual application, I need to assume $\sum x_i = O(\log n)$ and just need to show $|s_\lambda(x_1,\ldots, x_n) / s_\lambda(1,\ldots, 1)|^4 s_\lambda(1,\ldots, 1) = o(1)$ uniformly over $\lambda$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: The paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.0634.pdf  derives contour integral formulae for Schur functions that involve ratios $s_\lambda(x)/s_\lambda(1)$. These formulae might help in obtaining some of the bounds that you are after...

Comment: Thanks Suvrit. Yes I saw that paper earlier. They dealt with the case where $\vec{x}$ has arbitrary first $k$ entries, with $k$ fixed. In my case however I need $k$ to vary with $n$. The contour formula was also developed by my coauthor Bob Hough in our joint paper cited in that article.

Comment: Ah, I did not realize that! Do you have pointers to other places where this ratio $s_\lambda(x)/s_\lambda(1^n)$ shows up?

Comment: @Suvrit: Certainly. This is our paper on mixing time of random walk on $SO(n)$, http://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.2031v2.pdf. The contour formula for the type B root system case when $x_1 \neq 1$ but all other $x_i =1$ is lemma 2.1. We didn't look at type A, that is, Schur polynomial case. Also appendix B gives the more general case when $x_1, \ldots, x_k \neq 1$. I also found an interesting paper of yours ,http://suvrit.de/papers/sra_schur_published.pdf. It seems that HCIZ formula may be a good starting point for bounding $|s_\lambda(x_1, \ldots, x_n)|$ in the general case?

Comment: Thanks! I had first thought of that formula as a starting point, but then stopped because of the limitation to Hermitian matrices. But perhaps it is possible to use a suitable integral representation when bounding this quantity. Ever since I wrote the paper you mention above, I've been curious about these Schur ratios (and other closely related such ratios that occur in a bunch of related work)...

Comment: I am interested in the character ratio mainly from a random walk/Markov chain perspective, as they can be used to bound convergence rate using Diaconis and Shahshahani' upper bound formula, see e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1421974/can-there-be-a-diaconis-shahshahani-upper-bound-lemma-for-compact-groups/1454121#1454121. By the way do you know if HCIZ formula works for non-Hermitian matrices $A,B$ as well? In particular normal matrices would be interesting.

Comment: Have a look at Theorem 2 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/nlin/0209063.pdf --- as well as Theorem 4, Consequence 1, etc. --- that paper also contains citations to other work on integrals with complex matrices.

Comment: Aha! I just started reading that yesterday. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @Suvrit: I looked at the paper you mentioned above by Yu Orlov. It seems not very rigorous. I worked out a few examples that suggest HCIZ formula does not work for anti-hermitian A, B matrices, let alone normal ones. Is that true?

Comment: @JohnJiang Interesting. I had looked at that paper and I attributed some unclarity about their claims to my ignorance. Perhaps it is worthwhile to formulate an HCIZ integral for non Hermitian matrices as a question on MO? and I believe assuming normal matrices will be needed since we are integrating over $U(n)$. It should be possible to do a derivation directly without relying on Orlov's paper...

Comment: @JohnJiang I asked a colleague, and according to him: the determinantal formula for HCIZ is valid (by analytic continuation) for normal matrices. For non-normal matrices this does not work....so where's the catch?

Comment: @Suvrit Thank you for the quick followup. I was trying to work out the consequence of formula 1.6 in your paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.04753v3.pdf  in the case where $X_{2i} = -1$ and $X_{2i-1} = 1$. I was puzzled that when $n \to \infty$, this seems to give the same value as when all $X_i = 1$. But of course I forgot the denominator Vandermonde. Sorry for jumping to the conclusion. But this seems to open up some promising way to handle special cases of my  original questions, for $n \to \infty$ (the case I am interested in) and small $\lambda$.

Comment: @Suvrit Also the $\lambda_1$ in your formula is at least $n$, so my asymptotics argument also breaks down:)

Comment: @JohnJiang perhaps I'm misunderstanding. $\sum_i \lambda_i = n$, so that $\lambda_1 \le n$ and since $\lambda$ is a partition of $n$,  $\lambda_1 \ge 1$......(though thanks to your comment today and my colleague's response, now we know that the HCIZ identity holds for normal matrices!)...

Comment: @Suvrit I guess by $\lambda_1$ I was referring to $B(\lambda)_1$, which is $\lambda_1$ in your Theorem 4. Let me know if I misunderstood something. My earlier confusion was in the case $\lambda = (1,0,..0)$. I was under the false impression that $B(\lambda) = Diag(\lambda)$, then the exponent in the HCIZ formula becomes asymptotically constant as $n \to \infty$, which makes $F(\lambda) \to 1$, and $s_\lambda(\vec{x}) / s_\lambda(\vec{1}) \gg 1$, a clear contradiction. Now it seems HCIZ may be too weak for the purpose of bounding $s_\lambda(\vec{x}) / s_\lambda(\vec{1})$.

Comment: @Suvrit Instead I am having some success with nested contour integrals, along the same line as lucia's argument. I also wonder if there is some kind of duality between nested contour integral representation of $s_\lambda$ and HCIZ representation. Maybe  the former is simply related to integrating over the maximal torus?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32254/discussion-between-suvrit-and-john-jiang).

Comment: @JohnJiang MO moved the discussion to chat; I left a link for you there that you may find interesting!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the special case mentioned in the problem, I'll show the bound 
$$ 
|e_{n/2}(x_1,\ldots, x_n)| \le 2^{n/2}. 
$$ 
Let 
$$ 
F(z) = \prod_{j=1}^{n} (1+zx_j) = C \prod_{j=1}^{n} (z + \overline{x_j}), 
$$ 
where $C= \prod_{j} x_j$ has magnitude $1$.  (The roots of $F$ are $-\overline{x_j}$.)

Now by Cauchy's theorem 
$$ 
e_{n/2}(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=1} \frac{F(z)}{z^{n/2+1}} dz 
$$ 
and so in magnitude this is bounded by 
$$ 
\le \sup_{|z|=1} |F(z)|. 
$$

Now we use a very nice Theorem of [Carneiro and Vaaler](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.4050.pdf) (see Theorem 8.1 there), which gives a bound for the maximum of a polynomial whose roots are on the unit circle in terms of the first few symmetric power sums of the roots.  Let me quote their result fully:  Suppose $G(z) = \prod_{j=1}^{N}(z-\alpha_j)$ is a polynomial with $|\alpha_j| \le 1$ for all $j$.  Then for any natural number $K$ we have 
$$ 
\sup_{|z|\le 1} \log |G(z)| \le \frac{N}{K+1} \log 2 + \sum_{k=1}^{K} \frac{1}{k} \Big| \sum_{j=1}^{N} \alpha_j^k \Big|.
$$ 
This is Theorem 8.1, display (8.6) of their paper.

Apply this to our polynomial $F$, with $K=1$.  Since the sum of the $x_j$ is zero, by assumption, we deduce that 
$$ 
\max_{|z|=1} \log |F(z)| \le \frac{N}{2} \log 2, 
$$ 
which proves the claimed estimate.

Maybe there is an easier proof of this particular bound, rather than appealing to the Carneiro-Vaaler work.  I didn't see one immediately, and would be very interested if someone found an alternative approach.

Edit:  In the particular case $K=1$, which is what is needed for this question, [zeb](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2363/zeb) kindly showed me the following one line proof: assuming $|\alpha_j|\le 1$ and $|z|\le 1$ we have 
$$
|G(z)|^2 =\prod_{j} |z-\alpha_j|^2 \le \prod_{j} (2-2\text{Re }\overline{z}\alpha_j) \le 2^N \prod_j \exp(-\text{Re }\overline{z}\alpha_j)\le 2^N \exp\Big(\Big| \sum_j \alpha_j\Big|\Big).
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the nice harmonic analysis work of Carneiro and Vaaler. I wouldn't be able to find it myself in a million years.

Comment: I hope it's useful to you in general; and also I found this problem very interesting, so thanks!

Comment: Thanks Lucia and Zeb! I tried saddle analysis for the special case of $s_\lambda = e_{(n-1)/2}$ in trying to get the $\sqrt{n}$ factor, but the main difficulty seems to be that there could be $O(n)$ saddles. I may be able get $2^{n/2}$ with some additional small factors, because the saddle points all lie on unit circle. This is not the case for $e_k$, $k \notin \{(n\pm 1)/2\}$. Any idea to chip away a slight generalization of the above problem would be awesome.

Comment: This $K = 1$ proof is exactly the same as Carneiro and Vaaler's proof of that case. In Theorem 1.5 there, you have the degree one trigonometric polynomial $u_1(x) = \big(\log{2} - (e(x) + e(-x))/2\big)/2$. This one has Fourier coefficients of $-1/4$ at $n = \pm 1$, which is better than the estimate (1.49); hence the improved coefficient under the exponential in zeb's bound. But it is the unique polynomial $u_1(x)$ for degree $N = 1$ in Carneiro and Vaaler's theorem 1.5, that zeb made explicit.